# Assign User Identity to Azure Container Registry using Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-container-registry

How do I assign an User Identity to Azure Container Registry using Azure Powershell. I dont know a command specific to achieve this in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerregistry/?view=azps-10.1.0).

Result should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands that you should use for this aren't specific to the container registry. [Az.ManagedServiceIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.managedserviceidentity/?view=azps-10.1.0) is the cmdlet that contains commands to work with user identities.

Provided that the user identity and container registry already exist:

```
// Retrieve the registry that the identity should be assigned to.
$registry = Get-AzContainerRegistry -ResourceGroupName <resource_group_name> -Name <registry_name>

// Retrieve the existing user identity that you want to assign.
$userIdentity = Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName <resource_group_name> -Name <identity_name>

// Assign the identity to the container registry.
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userIdentity.PrincipalId -RoleDefinitionName AcrPull -Scope $registry.Id
```

You might need to change [`-RoleDefinitionName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles?tabs=azure-cli) to fit your exact use case.